# Timeout problems with bulk processing of files using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which I'm expecting to exceed 15 minutes of execution time. What should I do so it will continuously run until I processed all of my files?

Comment: better to go with fargate that is similar to lambda, all you need to setup your docker image and schedule your job that's it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, figure out how to scale your workload horizontally. This means splitting your workload so it runs on many lambdas instead of one "super" lambda. You don't provide a lot of details so I'll list a couple common ways of doing this:

- Create an SQS queue and each lambda takes one item off of the queue and processes it.
- Use an S3 trigger so that when a new file is added to a bucket a lambda processes that file.

If you absolutely need to process for longer than 15 minutes you can look into other serverless technologies like [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). Non-serverless options might include AWS Batch or running EC2.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Just wondering if a service like Step Function can help me with my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Step functions make sense when you have a defined workflow that needs to be completed. They take care of some things that aren't very fun to code like handling retries.

Answer (score 1):

15 minutes is the maximum execution time available for AWS Lambda functions.

If your processing is taking more than that, then you should break it into more than one lambda. You can trigger them in sequence or in parallel depending on your execution logic.

Comment: is it possible that Step Function service might help me with this?

Comment: Can be a choice https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/

Comment: as I understand it, my 'main function' will call the next function and then maybe process it on the next function but what if my main function exceeds 15 minutes as well, will it shut down the whole state machine?

Comment: But i think step functions may break as well, if you configure two lambda's and at some stage your execution goes beyons 30 min. So may not be a futuristic design.

Comment: No you will use SNS, to trigger the next lambda function when the first one is finished to do the rest of the processing.